# Error On Startup With Maven Dependancy

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror, bukkit

I am trying to set a maven dependency in my pom.xml but I am getting this error when I start my server up and run the method that uses the maven dependency: http://pastebin.com/AZrse1PW here is my pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/nEcS4drA .

Thanks for the help,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

You're not shading FancyMessage/Fanciful, so it does not exist at runtime. Add the following plugin to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>mkremins:fanciful</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```